# its giving me random numbers

Tags: c, output

I'm practicing some simple code. When my int number is 12 the output is -743998012 for some reason even with different numbers too.

here is my input code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int favnum;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &favnum);

    printf("My favorite number is %d.", &favnum);

    return 0;
}
```

I try to change variables like float or double didn't work

Comment: Doesn't your compiler show some warning about wrong type for format specifier `%d`? If yes, why did you ignore it? If no, you need to increase warning level.

Answer (score 2):

As said by user3121023, you need to remove the `&` in `printf("My favorite number is %d.", &favnum);`.

This is because when you add it, it means that you're not passing its value, but its address in the memory (the pointer where the variable `favnum` is stored). That's why in the line before you use `&` : you want to store the input of the console in the right memory location, where the variable `favnum` is.